# Passing variable (Int) to a View Control (Popover)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a `tableView` with 7 rows, each row is a different action.  When a user taps on a row, a view controller is shown as a popover and a text field is displayed for them to add a note.  I then want to save this note to Parse but I need to save the passedChildID with it and therefore it (passedChildID) needs to be passed from the `tableviewcontroller`.  I have this working in other area's of my app from one `tableView` to another `tableView` but for some reason it won't work with the popover.

The following code is in `SingleChildViewTableViewController`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "childToNote" {

        let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self

        let noteActionViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! actionNoteViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            noteActionViewController.passedChildID = passedChildID
        }
    }
    if segue.identifier == "childToItemNeeded" {
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

This builds and runs fine, but when I tap on that particular row, I get the following error.

`Could not cast value of type '<<app_name>>.SingleChildTableViewController' (0x10e1bef60) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x110bca128).`

I have tried moving the `let noteActionViewController...` code above the `let popoverViewController` figuring that the former was never getting run but that didn't change anything.

The segue is being performed as followed (in case it makes any difference).

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("childToNote", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I'm stumped because this code has worked elsewhere in my app without fail.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your problem lies in this line

```
  indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
```

the sender in this case you are telling it to be self, which is a UIViewController

```
  performSegueWithIdentifier("childToNote", sender: self)
```

You are then telling in the `indexPathForCell` line to cast it as a UITableViewCell but its of type `SingleChildTableViewController`.  So change the sender to be the UITableViewCell

Comment: I changed the sender to `performSegueWithIdentifier("childToNote", sender: UITableViewCell.self)` (the `.self` was required by xcode).  Now when I build and run I get the following error on tap.

`Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x108ae7150) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x108ae7128).` Which seems like an odd error.

Comment: You need to send a reference of the instance of that tableviewcell not the static self, do u need a code example?

Comment: I think I might have figured it out.

Comment: So I followed your advice above and changed the code as I mentioned.  I then commented out the `if let` statement and everything works.  Here's that section.
`let noteActionViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! actionNoteViewController
noteActionViewController.passedChildID = passedChildID`

Comment: indexPathForCell() method needs the selected UITableViewCell instance in order to work, however in this case it doesn't look like you need that to do anything.  you are triggering the segue from a selected tableview cell so form there you should be able to just pass the passedChildID into the new view controller

Comment: It's likely because each the passedChildID is common to all rows, I don't need the specific indexPath.row for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the indexPath as a local variable and when you select a cell you change the value of the variable.